# I need help figuring out where I should place the IF condition in the code block

Tags: python-3.x

```py
def user_input():
    print("Welcome to Smallest Number Finder")
    user_inp = input("Please Enter a List of Numbers separated by a Comma e.g 1, 2, 3...: ")
    if user_inp == "":
        print("Please Enter Numbers separated by a comma e.g 1, 2, 3...")
    else:
        user_list = list(map(float, user_inp.split(','))) # converting user input into a list
        return user_list

def smallest_number():
    smallest_so_far = None
    small_list = user_input()
    for small in small_list:
        if smallest_so_far == None:
            smallest_so_far = small
        elif small < smallest_so_far:
            smallest_so_far = small
    print("The Smallest Number is: ", smallest_so_far)

smallest_number()
```

Where/how should I put the IF condition to prompt the user to input numbers, in order to ensure no empty string is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to accomplish this would be to loop through the prompt *until* the user inputs something which is not an empty string.

```py
def user_input():
    print("Welcome to Smallest Number Finder")
    while True:
        user_inp = input("Please Enter a List of Numbers separated by a Comma e.g 1, 2, 3...: ")
        if user_inp:
            user_list = list(map(float, user_inp.split(',')))
            return user_list
        print("Please enter numbers separated by commas, e.g. 1,2,3")

def smallest_number():
    smallest_so_far = 0
    small_list = user_input()
    for small in small_list:
        if small < smallest_so_far:
            smallest_so_far = small
    print("The Smallest Number is:", smallest_so_far)

smallest_number()
```

Note that this does not cover the situation where the user enters something that is not an empty string nor is an integer, e.g. `"apple"`.

Comment: Thanks Jacob for bringing up the issue where the user enters a string. Let me try and fix that

Answer (score 0):

```
def user_input():
print("Welcome to Smallest Number Finder")
while True:
    try:
        user_inp = input("Please Enter a list of numbers separated by a comma e.g 1, 2, 3....: ") # user input
        if user_inp:
            user_list = list(map(float, user_inp.split(','))) # converts user input into a list
            return user_list
        else:
            print("List cannot be EMPTY!") # ensures the user does not enter an empty value
    except ValueError:
        print("Please use NUMERIC VALUES!") # runs user uses a string instead of either a float or integer

def smallest_number():
smallest_so_far = None # initializing smallest number so far to none(user might values < 0)
small_list = user_input() # assigning values received from user_input() to a variable
for small in small_list:  # looping through the list
    if smallest_so_far is None:
        smallest_so_far = small
    elif small < smallest_so_far:
        smallest_so_far = small
print("The smallest Number is: ", smallest_so_far)
```

smallest_number()